# Why isn't the icon color changing based on selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a sliding tabView with two tabs. The title color changes based on whether the tab is selected. It flicks between #9B9B9B' (lightGrey) for unselected and '#666768' (darkGrey) for selected.

I'm also rendering an icon next to the title. I want the icon color to also change based on which tab is selected.

For some reason, this is not happening and the color of the icon stays at unselected regardless of whether the tab is selected or not.

How can I fix this this? My code is below. Thank you.

```
  _renderLabel = (props: any) => ({ route, index }) => {
    const inputRange = props.navigationState.routes.map((x, i) => i);
    const outputRange = inputRange.map(
      inputIndex => inputIndex === index ? '#666768' : '#9B9B9B');
    const color = props.position.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange,
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
        <FontAwesome
          name={route.title === 'New' ? 'clock-o' : 'fire'}
          size={14}
          color={color === '#666768' ? '#666768' : '#9B9B9B'}
        />
        <Animated.Text style={[styles.label, { color }]}>
          {route.title}
        </Animated.Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Provide a working example (jsfiddle/snippet)

Comment: How can I do that with react native?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you are talking about react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change it to this:

```
const AnimatedFontAwesome = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FontAwesome);

...

<AnimatedFontAwesome
  name={route.title === 'New' ? 'clock-o' : 'fire'}
  size={14}
  style={{ color }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react` (web), you'd use `style`, not `color`. I searched around a bit, and I think it may be the same in `react-native`.

So, instead of:

```
color={color === '#666768' ? '#666768' : '#9B9B9B'}
```

try...

```
style={{ color: color === '#666768' ? '#666768' : '#9B9B9B' }}
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :(

FontAwesome has a prop called Color